# Problems with FPS(freezing), when changing color on scroll-x in a parallax site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have horizontal parallax site, it works fine, but when I add changing background-color on scroll like that:

```
var tennis = $('.tennis');
var tennisDivs = {};
var tennisColors = {};
$.each(tennis, function (index, value) {
    var color = $(value).data('color');
    var name = $(value).data('name');
    var left = $(this).offset().left;
    if ($(value).data('name'))
        tennisDivs[name] = left;
        tennisColors[left] = color;
});
var scrollArea = $('#tennis-container .slides');
var tempPosition = 'Info';
scrollArea.scroll(function () {
    var position = Math.floor($('#tennis-container .slides').scrollLeft());
    $.each(tennisDivs, function (index, value) {
        if ((value - 2300) <= position) {
            currIndex = index;
        }
    });
    if (tempPosition != currIndex) {
                tempPosition = currIndex;
                $('.slide__bg').attr('class','slide__bg').addClass('color-' + tempPosition);

            }
});
```

CSS:

```
.slide__bg {
    transition: background-color 0.8s linear 0.3s;
}

.color-info, .color-stars,.basic-color {
    background-color: #bdc1c6;
}

.color-courts {
    background-color: #75695f;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="tennis-container">
            <div class="slides">
                <div class="slide tennis-info info" id="tennis-info" data-name="Info" data-color="yellow">
                    <div class="slide__bg"></div>
                    <div class="slide__content"></div>
                </div>



             <div class="slide ...."  id="..." data-name="..." data-color="...">
                <div class="slide__bg"></div>
                <div class="slide__content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide ...."  id="..." data-name="..." data-color="...">
                <div class="slide__bg"></div>
                <div class="slide__content"></div>
            </div>

             </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, when the color changes on scroll, the site starts freezing and scrolling stops for couple seconds, as seen here:

[image: flame chart of freezing]

Also I try changing background-color using jQuery `animate()`, but nothing changes.

Fixes like:

1. Avoid resizing big images;
2. Remove background-size CSS property;

Don't work for me...

Comment: Your scroll function is not optimized, it looses much time to get elements via jquery. Try to use external variables as closures to prevent walking through DOM each time

Comment: I'm using this variable, it is - tempPosition; Color changes only once...  Now, i'm set variables to all jquery selectors in scroll function, but nothing change..

Comment: What is the length of `$('#tennis-container .slides')` ?

Comment: length 1, Im edit part of html

Answer (score 0):

It is all about performance issues. I have done some optimizations for the part of your code. Try this one:

```
var scrollArea = $('#tennis-container .slides');
var tempPosition = 'Info';
var slideBg = $('.slide__bg');
scrollArea.scroll(function () {
    var position = Math.floor(scrollArea.scrollLeft());
    $.each(tennisDivs, function (index, value) {
        if ((value - 2300) <= position) {
            currIndex = index;
        }
    });
    slideBg.attr('class','slide__bg').addClass('color-' + tempPosition);
});
```

Comment: As I wrore in my last comment "I'm using this variable, it is - tempPosition; Color changes only once... Now, i'm set external  variables to all jquery selectors in scroll function, but nothing changes."(Do the same thing as u).

Comment: `tempPosition` is never changing in this code, so may be there some algorithm mistakes? How do your slides work? On each scroll event your function adds class `color-Info` to `slideBg`

Comment: Im forgot to copy one part of my code(. Now, u can see where I  change temp position...But main question is why fps drops to 8-20 and and slow down site on change